# Number of items in string

Tags: php, string, facebook, count

I'm trying to get how many times **subject** occurs in this string from an FQL table.
I've tried SUM, Count, explode, etc. and every possible combination thereof that I could think of.

All I ever get is either the first item or an array of errors.

I'm new to PHP and get stuck on the dumbest things but after hours of unsuccessful attempts I turn to the professionals.

```
try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $fql    =   "SELECT subject FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()";
    $param  =   array(
                      'method'    => 'fql.query',
                      'query'     => $fql,
                      'callback'  => ''
                      );
    $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

    foreach($fqlResult as $row){
            //sum, count, explode or somthing? 

        $photo_tag_count = $row['subject'];

    }
        echo "$photo_tag_count";


} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
}
```

Here's an example of the array:

```
[{"subject": "123"},{"subject": "123"},{"subject": "123"}]
```

So I'm looking for `3` as the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-read OP, kind of confusing, based response on "example of array".

If $fqlResult is a string

```
echo count(explode(',', $fqlResult));
```

If $fqlResult is an array

```
echo count($fqlResult);
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution worked I overlooked counting $fqlResult. Everything else only returned 1.

Answer (score 1):

try `$photo_tag_count = count($row['subject']);`
or it would be try `$photo_tag_count = count($row);`
one of the two should work, I don't know what your 
array looks like, so its hard to figure out what to count.

Hell, you can even do this.

```
$photo_tag_count = 0 
 foreach($fqlResult as $row){

        if($row['subject']) {$photo_tag_count++;}

    }
        echo "$photo_tag_count";


} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ehime I've tried those solutions but I only get "1" returned or the first value in the array. I put an array example above. So with that I'm looking for 3 as the answer.